# Active não ficando selecionado ao click

Tags: javascript, html, css

Bom dia,

eu sei que deve ser uma coisa basica, mas estou tendo problemas com isso.

O site contem dois idiomas, ao clicar em uma bandeira, a linguagem do site muda e a bandeira referente a linguagem fica com cores, em quanto a outra bandeira fica em Preto e Branco, porem, quando eu clico em uma bandeira, ela fica selecionada e atualiza a pagina automaticamente, voltando para a outra bandeira.
Alguem poderia me ajudar?

**HTML**

```
             <div class="languages">
               <a href="<?=URL_SITE?>/idiomas/changeLanguage/portugues">
                   <img id="br" class="active" src="<?=ICONES?>br-flag.png">
                </a>

                <a href="<?=URL_SITE?>/idiomas/changeLanguage/espanhol">
                    <img id="es" src="<?=ICONES?>es-flag.png">
                </a>
            </div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('img').click(function() {
              $('img.active').removeClass("active");
              $(this).addClass("active"); 
            });
        });
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
.languages img{
         margin-left: 3px;
         filter: grayscale(1);
         -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
      }

.languages img:hover, .languages img.active{
         filter: grayscale(0);
         -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
      }
```

Comment: Qual é a linguagem que tens no servidor (imagino que PHP?)? A lógica que falta aqui pode ser feita no servidor. Se juntares ao link de cada imagem uma query string com por exemplo `?lang=br` no servidor podes ir buscar isso como um GET e renderizar as classes ou url de cada ficheiro png dependendo disso.

Answer (score 0):

Uma vez que redirecionas para outra página/url não precisas de ter a lógica no cliente e podes fazer tudo no PHP. Mesmo o que tens agora em jQuery podes fazer no servidor.

Seria algo assim:

```
<?php
    $lang = $_GET['lang'];    
?>
<div class="languages">
    <a href="<?=URL_SITE?>/idiomas/changeLanguage/portugues?lang=br">
        <img id="br" class="<?= $lang == 'br' ? 'active' : ''?>" src="<?=ICONES?>br-flag.png" />
    </a>

    <a href="<?=URL_SITE?>/idiomas/changeLanguage/espanhol?lang=es">
        <img id="es" class="<?= $lang == 'es' ? 'active' : ''?>" src="<?=ICONES?>es-flag.png" />
    </a>
</div>
```